# How to make bootable CD from .bin file?

Tags: assembly, bootloader, bin

I wrote a Program in Assembler language, saved as `boot.asm` and then compiled as `boot.bin`. 
In all tutorials that I saw, the bin file was tested in Bochs on virtual floppy disk, but I can't create virtual floppy disk on Windows 8.1 64 bit. How can I test it on a CD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would NOT try to test bootable images by really booting them on a real computer. Re-booting your PC will cost a lot of time and if there are bugs in the program (unintended writing to hard disk for example) you erase all data on the computer.

If I were you I would download a product like the VMware Player (it is free for non-commercial use) and test the boot file there. Just append as many bytes to the "boot.bin" file that the size is 1440*1024 bytes and use the file as disk image.

--- EDIT ---

As far as I understand you correctly your actual problem is that you do not have Bochs installed.

If this is true: Bochs is free for download, so why don't you just install it?

(I just suggested VMware player because I haven't used Bochs, yet. Maybe it was not a good idea.)

Reading the sentence "... but I can't create virtual floppy disk on Windows ..." I have the feeling that you are not fully aware what you are doing. This is why I suggest you to test your software using a virtual machine (like Bochs, VMware, Microsoft Virtual Machine, ...) and not to create a real bootable disk.

Using a virtual machine you do not risk damaging data on your computer - creating a bootable CD you do.

If you want to create a bootable CD: I don't know about Windows 8.1 but using the Windows 7 built-in CD-Rom burning mechanism you cannot create a bootable CD at all so you will require a third-party CD-burning software.

Comment: I was assuming he was going to use a second system with no hard drives attached (at least initially) to run the cd-rom based boot code. However, as you suggested, using a virtual environment would be much better. Does anyone make a virtual PC that includes source level debugging similar to the virtual ARM "armulators", used for ARM embedded software development?

Comment: You mean he should use an emulator which works just like VMware Player, except software based, so it's better for debugging? Something like Bochs perhaps?

Comment: @RossRidge: Sorry. As I wrote in my "edit" I understood the user in a way that his problem is NOT that he does not want to use Bochs but that he DOES NOT have Bochs installed. Therefore my actual suggestion should have been: Install such a software (which may be either Bochs or VMware).

Comment: @rcgldr: Writing this sentence with the "virtual floppy disks" I have the feeling that the user is not fully aware on what he is doing. I don't think he has a second system.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, my apologies for the undue snarkiness. Now that you point that out, I think his problem isn't that he doesn't have Bochs, but he doesn't know how to make a floppy disk image. Your suggestion to "append as many bytes to the "boot.bin" file that the size is 1440*1024 bytes and use the file as disk image" is probably the solution to his problem.

Comment: @RossRidge - armulators are more than just software emulators, they are also source level debuggers, that allow you to step through code in the virtual machine starting with the initial reset if wanted, similar to remote debugging (most commonly done when debugging device drivers) on a second computer with Visual Studio and tool kits. vmware workstation has a debugging mode, but I don't know if it's a source level debugger.

Comment: Bochs doesn't support source level debugging, it's not really designed to debug applications, but it does allow you to step through a boot loader at the instruction level. Which is pretty much the same thing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a bootable cd-rom. I would assume that most cd-rom and dvd-rom burner programs include this type of utility.

Comment: I don't know if most do, but it shouldn't be too hard to find one. If given a choice between floppy emulation, hard disk emulation or no emulation, pick floppy emulation.